# Apex triggers and Apex test class

Tags: apex, trigger

I have built this trigger:

```apex
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert) {

    List<Opportunity> lstOpportunity = (List<Opportunity>) Trigger.new;

    if(lstOpportunity.get(0).isClone()){
        lstOpportunity.get(0).ClonedSourceID__c = lstOpportunity.get(0).getCloneSourceId();   
    }
```

But I need to build an Apex class test to test the code coverage, so that I can get it deployed. I'm new to Apex code, so need some start help ;o)

Comment: Have you started writing the test class? Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: isTest

public class testopportunitytrigger {

 

    @isTest

    public static void getCloneSourceId ()

    {
        Opportunity ClonedSourceID = ClonedSourceID (ClonedSourceID = '0060Q00000JXXBPQA5', Cloned__c = 'TRUE');            

        System.startTest ();

       
        opp.ClonedSourceID__c= '0060Q00000JXXBPQA5';
        

        System.endTest ();

}